# Is there any workflow features in Apache Sling

Tags: apache, workflow, activiti, sling

Any body implemented workflow with apache Sling before? How easily to integrate third party workflow engine such as activiti with Apache Sling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know activiti but if you can package it in an OSGi bundle, it should be possible to use it in Sling.

The JCR and Sling observation mechanisms are very helpful in integrating with workflow systems, as they can call back into your code when content is modified in the JCR repository, in a very decoupled event-based way.